# Изменить переменные, при условии что время выполнения цикла вышло

Tags: php

У меня есть цикл, но иногда он уходит в бесконечное выполнение. Можно ли как нибудь через  сделать так, что если цикл выполняется дольше `2х секунд` то изменить переменные `$l_dict` и `$r_dict` на `$l_dict = 'dict'` и`$r_dict = 'dict'`

```
                do {
                $word_1 = changeRegister($l_dict);
                $word_2 = changeRegister($r_dict);
                $check = checkUpperRegister($word_1) && checkUpperRegister($word_2);
                } while ($check);

                    $summa = $p_1.$word_1.$p_2.$word_2.$p_3;
                    $password = preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $summa); 
                    $check_lentgh = mb_strlen($password, 'UTF-8') == $glength;

                } while (!$check_lentgh);
```

Comment: А почему именно через set_time_limit() ? Может с помощью time() ?

Comment: Напомнило одну [старую историю](http://phpfaq.ru/humor/continuous_function)

Comment: @Эдуард не обязательно set_time_limit(), про time() не знал:)

Comment: Намёк: если на генерацию пароля уходит больше одной миллионной доли секунды, возможно, что-то следует подправить в алгоритме.

Comment: @НиколайВасиленков   "цикл, но иногда он уходит в бесконечное выполнение" как это так? )) а не лучше найти и поправить причину, чем искать методы для исправления следствий....

Comment: С выше стоящим автором соглашусь. Выход по времени - дикий костыль. Вам нужно менять условие выполнения и отлавливать тот момент, когда цикл уходит в бесконечность.

Comment: @Ипатьев беда в том что иногда в словарях $r_dict и $r_dict не оказывается слов которые в сумме не будут превышать $glength т.е заданную длинну, поэтому я хочу менять словари(переменные) если такая ситуация возникнет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы ограничивал по количеству так

```
if(++$i == 100) break;
```

Но если уж надо по времени

```
$max = 1000; //maximum time in milliseconds
$start = microtime(true);

foreach($tasks as $t) {
    if (microtime(true) - $start > $max) {
         break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала определитесь, какую именно проблему пытаетесь решить. Ведь если подумать, то окажется что она в другом:

> иногда в словарях $r_dict и $r_dict не оказывается слов которые в сумме не будут превышать $glength

В итоге вопрос совсем в другом. Как и решение. Например, в вашем случае вы можете сложить слова в словари по длинам. Взять случайно словарь со словами любой длины. Взять из этого словаря случайное слово. Теперь отнимите от вашего *лимита на длину пароля* длину выбранного слова (словаря), получите остаток, который и будет равен длине слова (словаря) которое осталось дописать в пароль. Идёте в словарь этой длины и вынимаете оттуда случайное слово. В сумме они будут гарантировано давать нужную длину. Решение получится в одну итерацию, а значит вообще без циклов.